# VC++ LNK Errors With GLFW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, glfw

I'm using VC++ 2010 to work with some OpenGL. However, it's becoming a pain. I keep getting error codes again and again.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GL/glfw.h>


// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;
int main( void ){        
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() ){

            fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
            return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
    {
            fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
    }

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
            return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 01" );

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);

    do{
         // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

         // Swap buffers
         glfwSwapBuffers();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
         glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting from Visual Studio after compiling the code above. The output appears to be linking issues, however, I'm not sure how to correctly link the glfw requirements with the editor. Example errors:

```
Error   52  error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals  C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\Debug\OpenGL Fun.exe OpenGL Fun
Error   42  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4  C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   39  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16    C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   50  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8    C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(glext.obj)   OpenGL Fun
Error   45  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4    C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_glext.obj) OpenGL Fun
Error   41  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function _glfwOpenWindow   C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(window.obj)  OpenGL Fun
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\Main.obj  OpenGL Fun
Error   40  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main    C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\Main.obj  OpenGL Fun
Error   48  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetFloatv@8 referenced in function __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize   C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   49  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8 referenced in function __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   51  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetString@4 referenced in function __glfwParseGLVersion  C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(glext.obj)   OpenGL Fun
Error   43  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglCreateContext@4 referenced in function _createContext   C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   47  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglDeleteContext@4 referenced in function _destroyWindow   C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   44  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function _initWGLExtensions  C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
Error   46  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglMakeCurrent@8 referenced in function _createWindow  C:\Users\Username\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\GLFW.lib(win32_window.obj)    OpenGL Fun
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the solution explorer, right-click your project and select `properties`. From the configuration list box, select "all configurations". In the left pane, select the `Linker` sub-tree and then the `input` option. Add `opengl32.lib` under "Additional Dependencies".

Comment: I'm sill getting some errors Error 39 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Chefomsky\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\Debug\OpenGL Fun.exe 1 1 OpenGL FunError 38 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _main C:\Users\Chefomsky\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL Fun\OpenGL Fun\Main.obj OpenGL Fun

Comment: @NathanHatch-Martinez: For the LNK1120 error, please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7410844/716076). For the LNK2019, I recommend [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, side note: I used the wrong libs... Thank you for your help.