# create an instance of a class in another header c++

Tags: c++, oop, header

I am quite new at programming in C++... I started out programming in C# a year ago so I'm failing on some really basic stuff... I think...
I created a class called vector that is a point in 3d space the header of which looks like this:

```
class vec3
{
    double x, y, z;
public:
    vec3();
    vec3(double x, double y, double z);
    double calculateLLength(void);
    double distance(double x1, double y1, double z1);
    double distance(const vec3 &vec);
    ~vec3(void);
};
```

after this I was supposed to write a class called sphere which centerpoint is
a vector from my vector class which looks lite this (sphere header):

```
#pragma once
#include "vec3.h"
class Sphere
{
    vec3 center1;
    double x, y, z;
    double radius1;
    static const double PI;

public:

    //constructs
    Sphere(double x, double y, double z, double radius);
    Sphere(vec3 center1, double radius);
    //Methods
    bool inside(const vec3 &center);
    bool overlap(const Sphere &sphere);
    double area();
    double volume();
    ~Sphere(void);
};
```

the error I get is:

> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I tried to Google this and spent most of my Saturday trying to fix it but can't....

(here is the cpp files if anyone needs them!)

Sphere.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Sphere.h"
#include "vec3.h"
#include <math.h>

const double Sphere::PI = 3.1415926535;
Sphere::Sphere(double centerX, double centerY, double centerZ, double radius)
{
    vec3 center(centerX, centerY, centerZ);
    radius1 = radius;
}

Sphere::Sphere(vec3 center, double radius)
{
    center1 = center;
    radius1 = radius;
}
bool Sphere::inside(const vec3 &center)
{
    if(radius1 < center1.distance(center))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
bool Sphere::overlap(const Sphere &sphere)
{
    if(this->center1.distance(sphere.center1) < radius1 + sphere.radius1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
double Sphere::area()
{
}

double Sphere::volume()
{
}

Sphere::~Sphere(void)
{
}
```

vec3.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "vec3.h"
#include <math.h>


vec3::vec3(double x, double y, double z)
{
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
    this->z=z;
}

double vec3::calculateLLength()
{
    return sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
}

double vec3::distance(double x1, double y1, double z1)
{
    return sqrt( ((this->x - x1)*(this->x - x1)) + ((this->y - y1)*(this->y - y1)) + ((this->z - z1)*(this->z - z1)) );
}

double vec3::distance(const vec3 &vec)
{
    return sqrt( ((this->x - vec.x)*(this->x - vec.x)) + ((this->y - vec.y)*(this->y - vec.y)) + ((this->z - vec.z)*(this->z - vec.z)) );
}

vec3::~vec3(void)
{
}
```

Comment: what's the detail of `error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`?

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall vec3::vec3(void)" (??0vec3@@QAE@XZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have declared default constructor of vec3 but you haven't provide a definition for it. Add below code to vec3.cpp:

vec3.cpp:

```
vec3::vec3()
:x(0),y(0),z(0)
{
}
```

Side note, `Sphere::area` and `Sphere::volume` need to return value as they are declare to return `double`:

```
double Sphere::area()
{
   return 0.0;
}

double Sphere::volume()
{
   return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was my defult constructor... thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is the actual code, you're getting that message because the compilation failed earlier - `Sphere::area` and `Sphere::volume` *must* return something, but yours are empty.

Since the compilation of `Sphere.cpp` failed, there's no "Sphere.o" file, and the linker complains about everything that would have been defined there.

When you're building C++, it's important to go through the errors beginning with the first one, as that one very often causes more errors later.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely forgetting to link *all* your source `cpp` files together when compiling the actual program.

By *declaring* your classes in your header files (*.h), you're only describing how the classes look like.  You also need to *define* the implementation of those classes; these are what's written in the source files (*.cpp).  When you link the final program all together, make sure that you're linking all the compiled source files, or the linker will not be able to resolve *definitions* for things you've *declared*.

I don't know how your build environment is set up, but the solution in a typical IDE is to make sure all your sources are marked as used to create the final executable.

Comment: That's very unlikely. VS automatically compiles/links every cpp added to a project unless you specifically tell it to ignore one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post and see if it helps you...

[C++ Fatal Error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals)

From what I understand, when you setup the project you didn't specify that you would be using a windows application, therefore it didn't associate the windows api with your application.

Comment: He could very well be working on a console application. There is no indication that window's windows library are being used.

Comment: No i tried that... redid the entire project just to be sure in an console application...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exact error you get it's hard to say exactly what the problem is. The error you are getting is caused by your linker complaining that it can not find the implementation of one "symbol" (=function, class...) you defined. This kind of error could be caused by a wrong usage of the precompiled headers in Visual Studio ("stdafx.h"). You should try to create a new project and deactivate precompiled headers, you don't need them for small projects. And by the way in C++ you should rather include `<cmath>` which wraps the C library `<math.h>` in the `std` namespace.