# How to make a class in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, object

How can I make a custom class and use its methods in Visual Studio 2012?

I try this but always get a fatal error:

> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: Try this, while I search for something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals

Answer (score 0):

ah just add className:: by the class. c++ use header file and on cpp file all method/functions have a scope operator. Or leave the header file and write directly. See the constructor declaration and do the same.