# OpenGL, Visual C++ 2012 compiling errors

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I am trying to compile my Win32, OpenGL program in visual studio 2012 and I keep getting this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16   C:\Users\Chief\Documents\Programming\C++\Projects\Practice\Practice\WinMain.obj Practice

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Chief\Documents\Programming\C++\Projects\Practice\Debug\Practice.exe   1   1   Practice
```

Here is my code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>

#include <gl/GL.h>

HWND hwnd;
int clientWidth = 800;
int clientHeight = 600;

bool InitMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance);
LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if(!InitMainWindow(hInstance))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    MSG msg = {0};
    while(WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            //This is where all my updating and rendering stuff will go
        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

bool InitMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = MsgProc;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Project2DClass";
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to register window class", NULL, NULL);
        return false;
    }

    RECT r = { 0, 0, clientWidth, clientHeight };
    DWORD style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    AdjustWindowRect(&r, style, false);
    int width = r.right - r.left;
    int height = r.bottom - r.top;
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2 - width/2;
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2 - height/2;

    hwnd = CreateWindow("Project2DClass", "Project 2D", style, x, y, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create window", NULL, NULL);
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); 

    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can resolve this and what I have done wrong? And once again I am using microsoft visual studio 2012 and openGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing one or more libraries at the link step: OpenGL32.lib

You need to do the following

Add "opengl32.lib " to Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Where are those libs though

Comment: these libs should be installed and the path set when you install openGL. the actual location would be system32 or their installation dir.

Comment: I only needed opengl32.lib

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to the `opengl32` library, probably just `opengl32.lib`.

See also the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318372.aspx) (but remember this is technically written for OpenGL 1.1 which MS supports, any newer functionality will need to be catered for in some other way, like GLEW, GLUT, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

for the 1120 error i recommend seeing this link: [C++ Fatal Error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals/7410844#7410844) 
                                                                                                            for 2019 :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: The `1120` error was caused by the `2019` error because there was no `.exe` to run. So now that I have solved the `2019` error it's working great there is no `1120` error anymore