# Multiple Ui in Qt Project

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator

How can I make multiple Ui forms in Qt Creator and link them?
I want to have a button in my mainwindow.ui and when it's triggered i want the other ui be shown.
how can I do it?

I have two Qt Form Classes:

1. mainwindow
2. mainwindow2

I tried this code in main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow2.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
MainWindow2 w2;
w2.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

but this errors occur:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall MainWindow2::~MainWindow2(void)" (??1MainWindow2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
>
> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MainWindow2::MainWindow2(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow2@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> release\testtest.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Comment: HTH http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: Did you define the constructor and the destructor in your `MainWindow2` class?

Answer (score -1):

take a look to [slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) and play with otherUI.show() / otherUI.hide() if you want basics interactions.

For the liker problem : From  [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/b83e4884-9dec-4d67-ab92-90d5b6c8c51c/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410844/2307070)

> When you created the project, you made the wrong choice of application
>   type. When asked whether your project was a console application or a
>   windows application or a DLL or a static library, you made the wrong
>   chose windows application (wrong choice).
>
> Go back, start over again, go to File -> New -> Project -> Win32
>   Console Application -> name your app -> click next -> click
>   application settings.
>
> For the application type, make sure Console Application is selected
>   (this step is the vital step).
>
> The main for a windows application is called WinMain, for a DLL is
>   called DllMain, for a .NET application is called
>   Main(cli::array ^), and a static library doesn't have a
>   main. Only in a console app is main called main

Comment: how can I add another ui and use it. I tried adding "Qt Designer Form Class" and "Qt Designer Form" but I don't know how to define them. In class form, I tried to show the otherui but link error occurred.

Comment: I added another class and tried to show it in my main.cpp but again link error occurred

Comment: @Aidin.T which error? Add it to your question and add a little bit of code if possible

Comment: ok, I just created a new Qt Console Application, so now I can add Qt Designer Form Class?

Comment: @Aidin.T No, the console application was good for the other case, in yours you should create a Qt graphic application