# Creation of window (C)in visual studio2010

Tags: visual-c++

When building my application am getting this error, am a fresher in windows programming... any solutions, please?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: window1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:Visual Studio 2010\Projects\window1\Debug\window1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals It might help answer your question

Comment: The Linker > System > SubSystem setting is wrong.  Probably some others as well.  Fall in the pit of success by just using the proper project template to get started, use Win32 > Win32 Project.  Delete the pre-generated skeleton code and paste your own.