# Basic C++ function to Python via Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a very basic setup to experiment on how to expose a C++ function to Python via Cython. However, I keep getting the following error. What am I missing?

```
foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol cppFoo
C:\git\cythonTest\foo.cp38-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

---

`cppFoo.h`

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

double cppFoo(double x, int y);

#endif
```

`cppFoo.cpp`

```
#include "cppFoo.h"

double cppFoo(double x, int y)
{
    return 2 * x + y;
}
```

`cfoo.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "cppFoo.h":
    double cppFoo(double x, int y)
```

`foo.pyx`

```
from cfoo cimport cppFoo

def pyFoo(double x, int y):
    return cppFoo(x, y)
```

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("foo.pyx"), requires=['Cython'])
```

Running with `python setup.py clean build_ext --inplace`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Fatal Error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410798/c-fatal-error-lnk1120-1-unresolved-externals)

Comment: Not really. Although perhaps it does and I'm too dumb to realize it.

Comment: I've tried (i) not doing anything and simply calling the python command at the end of the post and (ii) compile it first with `gcc -c cppFoo.cpp` and then compile the cython stuff. However, both give me the same error.

Comment: Glad you got it working... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. `cppFoo.cpp` was not being recognized as a source file. Adding the following line at the top of `foo.pyx` was enough.

```
# distutils: sources = cppFoo.cpp
```